# How do I Create a Maven Project in Android?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-2.3

I would like to move some of my code to a library project for multiple applications and other people to use. It would be great if I could add my library to Maven. I've read through a few tutorials online, but some of the information is different. Is there a recommended way of doing this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with your project?

Comment: You mean you want your artifact to appear in the main Maven repo?

Comment: I have some utility fragments that I share across multiple apps and that I would like to open source for other to use in a library

Comment: You do not want to mix gradle and maven projects in the same repo. Just create a normal java module with gradle alongside your "app" module.

Comment: Thanks @JaredBurrows I think i may have asked the wrong question. I'm trying to create a gradle module thats hosted on maven central for others to pull

Comment: Are you asking how to publish an artifact to maven central?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I'm asking how to have an app module hosted so that other can add it to their gradle script. For example, if I wanted to publish a framework or a library that was used across multiple apps, how do I do that? Is there a clear tutorial somewhere?